# Laravel 5 Validator - required_with and required_if on same field

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a unique situation, involving validating a user on a mailing list. I have 3 fields: `on_mailing_list`, `mailing_address`, and `mailing_email`.

The idea is, neither `mailing_address` nor `mailing_email` should be required if the person is not on the mailing list.
However, if they are on the mailing list, they need at least one of the 2 pieces of contact information.

My first thought is something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'on_mailing_list' => '',
    'mailing_address' => 'required_if:on_mailing_list,1,mailing_email,',
    'mailing_email' => 'required_if:on_mailing_list,1,mailing_address,',
);
```

But my first thought is: "I'd be surprised if Laravel didn't hate that empty *value* in `required_if`..."

I'm not sure if the empty value was throwing it off, or not, but it still thinks they are required when `on_mailing_list` is false.

So I tried the following...

```
$rules = array(
    'on_mailing_list' => '',
    'mailing_address' => array(
        'required_if:on_mailing_list,1',
        'required_without:mailing_email'
    ),
    'mailing_email' => array(
        'required_if:on_mailing_list,1',
        'required_without:mailing_address'
    ),
);
```

But this doesn't work, because `required_without` still triggers when `on_mailing_list` is false.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create two sets of rules and two different validation functions.

Comment: While that is an idea, in reality the form is far larger and more complex than this. I could add the validation rules in conditionally, but the hope here is that a built-in solution exists.